# How to make vegan mayo with soy lechitin, oil and water without failing

Tags: vegan, soy, emulsion, mayonnaise

I have soy lecithin with me. How do I blend this with water and oil to make vegan mayonnaise? I have tried a lot of times but every time I get a thin oily watery stuff.

The procedure is-

1)Mix 2 tbsp lecithin with 3 tbsp water.

2)Add the mixture with 1 tbsp oil and mix in the blender.

3)Repeat step 2 four times.

No matter how much oil I add, it doesn't work. When I use homemade soymilk instead of water+lecithin, it works.

Answer (score 4):

When you add soy lecithin to your water-oil mixture and agitate it, it only helps to combine oil and water but does not give it the consistency of egg-based mayonnaise. It's way more fluid/watery. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFtm56Njzx8) explains the chemical process behind this emulsion and gives you an idea of how this mix would look like and why. If you are really interested in the chemistry behind it.

To give your vegan mayo the body and stability of egg-based mayo when mixing it, you would need to add a base like vegetable or tofu when mixing soy lecithin, oil, and water.

The Soya milk works as it contains natural emulsifiers which bind the oil to make it nice and fluffy and mayo-like.

I found [this](https://www.seriouseats.com/how-to-make-vegan-mayonnaise-mayo) blog post very helpful when making vegan mayo with a friend for the first time. The eggplant really does the trick!

Comment: Hi Hannah, I was rather confused by your first sentence, because at first I parsed it as trying to explain a difference between adding the lecithin "before emulsifying" and "after emulsifying" (which wouldn't happen anyway). I edited it to prevent others falling into the same language trap, I hope I was able to convey your meaning well.

Comment: @Hannah I added boiled potatoes in the watery goop that I had got with some more lecithin. The result was great mayo, but it is unstable. As soon as I remove it from the blender, it starts getting thin and loses its mayo feel. After an hour, there is a layer of oil and blended potato separated. How do I fix this so atleast I can have the stability for atleast like 15 minutes so I can eat it thick?

Comment: @Sam oh the lecithin should in theory avoid that the oil and water separate again. When exactly did you add the lecithin? Did you blend it all together at once?

Comment: I had mixed it with water then added it to the blender with some oil. Then added more oil gradually. After 1 day, I blended the potatoes with this mix then added some lechitin directly in the resultant thick mix then blended again.

Comment: I would try to create first a base using the lecithin before emulsifying. Therefore I would blend water or lemon juice and if you like mustard and garlic and the chosen vegetable together with the lecithin. After this has been set, you pour oil on top and allow it to settle for 15 seconds. Then you blend the oil into your base. 
This should hopefully help the emulsion to last longer. 
Reblending should always help troubleshooting your current mix, to get the mayo consistency back.